Use virtual env while debugging Python app in Visual Studio Code
I have some Python source code and want to debug this code via VS Code.
I set-up a virtual environment through Ctrl+Shift+P->Select Interpreter, and this virtual environment is shown in the right-bottom corner of VS Code. If I execute Terminal->New Terminal command, the new terminal would be opened with venv activated.
But If I press F5 or Ctrl+F5, another terminal would be opened, and in this terminal venv would not be activated. I have to stop debugging, activate venv manually by
source myvenv/bin/activate

and press F5 again. Now I can debug using venv.
Do I can make VS Code open terminal for debug with venv activated?
This is an example of my launch configuration:
{
    "name": "MyConfiguration",
    "type": "debugpy",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "test.py",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": false
}

Among other things, I use subprocess.run(..) in my Python code and want this subprocess to be executed with venv activated.

False not false

It's JSON it should be false only.

In the launch configuration, point to the python interpreter within your env. This should activate your venv automatically while debugging.
Try this:
   {
        "name": "MyConfiguration",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "test.py",
        "pythonPath": "venv_Path/bin/python",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    }


Solved by adding to .bashrc
[[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]] && . "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path bash)"

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22860
